# Headers nomenclature -- rows and positions

Tags: components, pins, header

I want to but this kind of header -- essentially 6 pins, 3 in each row:
[image]

On the mouser search, there are parameters called rows and positions. I want to be sure what this would be called ---

1. 2-rows 6-position (I think its this, but want to confirm)
2. 2-row 3-postion

Answer (score 1):

**2-rows 6-position**

Typically the total number of conductors is stated explicitly (6 in your case) and the number of rows (2) is a subcategory in the product range.

Examining the datasheet and/or the technical drawing (these are sometimes separate documents available for download from the product page in the distributor's website) will remove the ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

**General Case**

The classification of headers and connectors as to number of positions versus other parameters such as number of rows or number of columns is manufacturer specific.

There is however a "general standard" that number of total positions (i.e. circuit connections) is part of the part number and then number of rows being a secondary part of the part number. It then follows that the number of columns in each row is:

```
# col = # positions / # rows
```

**Non Standard Case**

An example of one manufacturer that uses their own technique is Samtec. They have typically had number of rows and number of columns both be part of the part number. In their case they use number of positions to be equal to the number of columns. So the total connections becomes:

```
# Samtec connections = # positions * # rows
```

**Conclusion and Caution**

What this means is that it always really really necessary to consult manufacturer data sheets and product drawings every time you embark to use a new type of connector or header assembly.

And while you are checking make sure to carefully check how the connector position counting / numbering is done. There are some "general standards" with this but by no means is it universal. Failure to be careful will end up with schematics and PC boards that to not match reality.

Answer (score 0):

Digikey's description is

- Connectors, Interconnects  > Rectangular - Board to Board Connectors - Headers, Receptacles, Female Sockets  >
- Common abbreviated descriptor is **CONN THRU HOLE RCPT .100" 6POS DUAL GOLD. 
  xx height**. it appears to be 0.35 " Amp # 215309-3
- **6 pos Dual** automatically means 2 row x 3

options include header height (check), plating material (gold preferred) and thickness (thicker is better) (gold over nickel over spring alloy) Spacing, pin size and thru hole length are standard.

http://www.digikey.com/product-search/compare/en?returnUrl=%2Fproduct-search%2Fen%2Fconnectors-interconnects%2Frectangular-board-to-board-connectors-headers-receptacles-female-sockets%2F1442673%3Fk%3Dheader%2Bsocket%26k%3D%26pkeyword%3Dheader%2Bsocket%26pv28%3D74%26pv28%3D1993%26pv28%3D50%26pv88%3D7%26pv89%3D1%26pv90%3D2%26FV%3Dfff40016%252cfff80371%26mnonly%3D0%26newproducts%3D0%26ColumnSort%3D0%26page%3D1%26stock%3D1%26quantity%3D0%26ptm%3D0%26fid%3D0%26pageSize%3D500&part=A106656-ND&part=A106661-ND&part=SAM1086-03-ND&part=SAM1092-03-ND&part=SAM1088-03-ND

mouser's search is less descriptive with many not in stock
http://ca.mouser.com/Search/ProductDetail.aspx?qs=dzoBT28%252baSR99RFWMIhLFg%3d%3d

example http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/18/bus-12-055-946221.pdf

you must verify height for interboard space. and choose best contact / price options

If you plan on thousands of insertion cycles a lubricant helps.
The recommended lubrication is Nye 176 as a 5% solution of 111 trichloroethane.